# Add superscript in Label - Flex

Tags: apache-flex, superscript

How do I use superscript text in Flex? I tried sup tag in htmlText, but it doesn't work

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

In Flex 3, not really easily possible. In Flex 4, easily possible using FTE/TLF. See http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/demos/ and also the "baselineShift" style in spark.components.RichText

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done in Flex without hacks. Can hardly be done in Flash unless you use certain fonts.

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:HGroup gap="0">
  <s:Label text="234 cm" fontSize="14"/>
  <s:Label text="2" baselineShift="4" fontSize="10"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

The HGroup might not actually be needed, depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with your own control that uses multiple UITextFields with different font sizes and positions, but I can imagine this being a painful control to get right...it just depends on how badly you need it.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think you can do it on a label, maybe you can replace it with a RichText box, as I have done here: [How to use superscripting in flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601507/how-to-use-superscripting-in-flex/13164076#13164076)

I believe that only HTML 1.0 is allowed in a .htmlText -- You must use Flow Text to get it to work.